# Viewable content changes on set time interval - but previous content flashes into view afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building an example of a web-hosted menu that will be broken into a number of blocks of content. Some content will change at a set time of day (breakfast to lunch menu). The content is changing at the appropriate time, but seconds later the previous content reappears in a flashing manner several times over the course of 1-2 minutes before stopping.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    SetImage();
    window.setInterval(SetImage,1000);
});

function SetImage(){     
    var nowdate = new Date() ;
    
    var waketime = new Date();     
    waketime.setHours(6);
    waketime.setMinutes(30);
    
    var bedtime = new Date();     
    bedtime.setHours(12);
    bedtime.setMinutes(00);
    
    if(waketime < nowdate  && nowdate < bedtime){
         $('.day').show();
         $('.night').hide();
    }else{
         $('.night').show();
         $('.day').hide();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col content">
 <img class="day" src="images/img05.jpg"/>
 <img class="night" src="images/img07.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="col sidebar">
 <img class="day" src="images/img06.jpg"/>
 <img class="night" src="images/img08.jpg"/>
</div>
```

http://damianzannini.com/HTH/index5.html

As state previously, I'm able to get the content to change at the appropriate time, but the previously visible (and now what should be hidden) content continues to reappear after a few seconds (usually flashing). My goal is to have it so that once the content changes, this flashing doesn't happen and the content doesn't change until the next appointed time.

Comment: If it's helpful, I'm able to inspect the elements while it's "flashing" - the old and new content cycle back and forth between "display: none" and "display: inline"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your website you put the script outside of body, which is an issue.

I would try adding this css so that when the page loads, both get hid immediately because jquery doesn't load and run before CSS does.

```
.day, .night{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've correct the script being outside the body and implemented the css line you recommend. It seems I'm still getting the same behavior when the items change (only around the time the change happens). It's odd to me that there's a conflict occurring that seems to be only at that point but stops a minute or two afterwards.

Comment: I've just tried using <= rather than < in addition to using setSeconds() for the time it's set to change. Content now changes over without flashing the previous! Thanks a million!